# Entering username and password for Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift, rest, curl, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire to do a GET request for my iOS app, but I don't really know how to enter my username and password.

The cURL command that ran successfully was

curl -k -u user:pw https://url/**cli**/method

and it returned the correct JSON

for Alamofire I tried

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, self.baseURL + method, parameters: params).responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in
            println(JSON)
```

where baseURL + method is https://url/**rest**/method

and params is

```
let params = [
            "username" : self.username.text,
            "password" : self.password.text
        ]
```

but when I try it it says that

NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure you use GET for login?

Comment: it isn't a login request it's a request to see all the running applications on a server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently there is a thing for this in Alamofire. I need to do...

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, self.baseURL + method, parameters: nil)
    .authenticate(user: self.username.text, password: self.password.text)
    .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in
        println(JSON) 
}
```

To authenticate myself.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is a problem with the certificate. My bets are that it is *invalid*. Unfortunately, Alamofire doesn't support overriding invalid certificates at the moment (like AFNetworking does for example).

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/225) thread for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm having trouble wrapping my head at what it means to be "invalid" and why would anyone want to allow an invalid certificated?

Comment: Well, for example Alamofire sees self-signed certificates as invalid, so if you signed it yourself and not certification authority, then you'll receive this error.