# Swift curl --user post

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, connection, alamofire

I have this :

```
curl https://address --user appID:appKey -d grant_type=password -d scope=read -d format=json -d username="username" -d password="password"
```

and I try to convert it in swift. Can you help me please?

> *There is no link between **the username and the password** and **the appId and the appKey***

I already have that :

```
private func LoadKey() {
    var params : [String:String] = ["grant_type":"password",
                                    "scope":"read",
                                    "format":"json",
                                    "username":"myUsername",
                                    "password":"myPassword"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response.result.value)
    }   
}
```

and I have no idea about how give the appId and appKey

Thank you in advance for your answer and have a good day.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I update my post

Comment: You can use a tip I gave there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637437/alamofire-with-d/53637821#53637821 to understand what parameter to put in the Alamofire Request construction. You'll see then (and you didn't give it) that's it's missing the --user param, so Alamofire + --user gives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434008/entering-username-and-password-for-alamofire-request

Answer (score 0):

Since the curl command doesn't specify an authentication type I assume it's basic authentication. If so please try the following:

```
private func LoadKey() {
    var params : [String:String] = ["grant_type":"password",
                                    "scope":"read",
                                    "format":"json",
                                    "username":"myUsername",
                                    "password":"myPassword"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                    .authenticate(user: "appID", password: "appKey")
                    .responseJSON { (response) in
                print(response)
            } 
}
```

Best,
Carsten